# How can I add social icons in LibreOffice document?

Tags: icons, libreoffice, fonts

I need social icons eg a pin icon for location, a LinkedIn icon, and a phone icon. I know that I can add special characters by clicking on `insert > special characters` and then choosing symbols based on fonts. Unfortunately, I don't see the required symbols in the fonts.

example showing email, LinkedIn, location icons
[image]

Where can I get the icons and add them to my document?

**Version Information**

Version: 7.3.7.2 / LibreOffice Community
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: By social icons, do you mean emojis?

Comment: I am creating a custom cv so I think SVG icons will work

Comment: I don't get what kind of icons you want to enter? Are you trying to enter emojis? https://fostips.com/insert-emojis-special-characters-linux/

Comment: I am really sorry that I was not able to explain what I am looking for. You can check this example: https://www.google.com/search?q=cv+with+social+icons&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwirjIjjo_v-AhUCrycCHXrUBpEQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=cv+with+social+icons&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoFCAAQgAQ6BwgAEIoFEENQuwJY9ixg0i5oAnAAeACAAYgCiAGjGJIBBDItMTOYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=UjhkZKubA4LensEP-qibiAk&bih=762&biw=1478&hl=en#imgrc=SWD_QCVb5TJ3SM
In the top left corner, there is a contact section, and each contact detail has a symbol with info eg LinkedIn, email, etc. I want those icons.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes this is the correct answer. I downloaded the icon as a png from here: https://icons8.com/icons/set/email and inserted it as an image and then resized it.

Comment: This LaTeX template has some of these icons https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV. However, that is not Libreoffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to get icons like this into your document is to find and obtain the icons online somewhere, resize them, and embed them, such as in PNG or such formats.

There's no icon set that includes these, so you are unfortunately relegated to finding such sets online yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to insert icons as special characters by installing the relevant font. e.g. Font Awesome:

```
sudo apt install fonts-font-awesome
```

Be aware this has portability issues since it will require anyone viewing the document to also have this font installed. Either exporting to PDF or embedding the font in the document when sharing would workaround this.

To use an icon select from `Insert->Special Characters` in LO:

[image: special characters]

or copy the Glyph from the Font Awesome website:

[image: select glyph]